# Writing uint16 using big-endian where the least significant byte of the pair is zero

Tags: c#, endianness

[Apologies for the wall of text, I'm not hugely sure if the problem is my misunderstanding of writing values in big-endian order, converting the source value into bytes, or a misunderstanding of a file format, so I've tried to include enough background information that someone can tell me of my stupidity.]

Some time ago I wrote some code that would read and write Adobe Photoshop Color Swatch files (`*.aco`). I wrote the code, I tested it with unit tests, and via the simple expedient of actually opening a generated swatch file in an older version of Photoshop, and all seemed well.

In an ACO file (sticking to RGB color space only for the purposes of this question), each color channel is a `uint16` using the full range of 0-65535 for the value, and is written to files in big-endian order. In the original versions of my code, I was using `System.Drawing.Color` which of course only does the range 0-255, so I would multiple and divide by 256 as appropriate.

This is an example of how I would write the values to a file

```
private void WriteInt16(Stream stream, short value)
{
  stream.WriteByte((byte)(value >> 8));
  stream.WriteByte((byte)(value >> 0));
}
```

I break an `int16` into two bytes, and write them using big-endian order. Simple enough I thought.

After the code was in production use, I received bug reports starting that third party applications that supported aco files were reading palettes created by my code as pure black. I still found Photoshop itself was very happy with the files, but I did find a third party application that turned them into black. So the problem definitely existed.

The screenshot below is from a diagnostic tool I ended up writing trying to work out what was going on. (I've munged the screenshot a bit to try and make it fit in this narrow width, but it should show enough detail)

The block on the left is an original aco file. The block on the right is the same file, after it had been re-saved using my code. The coloring is fairly irrelevant for this post, save that the pale salmon is the RGB color data (plus a forth dummy channel).

[image]

From looking at this image, the problem was readily discoverable. Due to my conversion of (byte)*256, this meant that one byte was *always* zero, and when written out as zero it seemed that every other third party application in existence read the file wrong, except for Photoshop.

Newer versions of the code look like this

```
public static void WriteBigEndian(this Stream stream, ushort value)
{
  byte[] buffer;

  buffer = new byte[2];

  buffer[0] = (byte)(value >> 8);
  buffer[1] = (byte)value;

  if (buffer[1] == 0 && buffer[0] != 0)
  {
    buffer[1] = buffer[0];
  }

  stream.Write(buffer, 0, 2);
}
```

Where I "fix" the problem changing the 0 byte to match the non-zero byte. I also store and use the original `uint16` values to avoid lose of precision by converting them to bytes and back, but that's beside the point.

My question (finally) is **WHY** does this work. I don't understand the fix I stumbled into (this was my first time at working with big-endian ordering). Does big-endian order for `uint16` not support a non-zero byte followed by a zero byte, have I misunderstood how to break down a `uint16` into its component bytes, am I misunderstanding the [ACO file format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577411_pgfId-1055819), or is it just the case that all of these programs read the files wrong (that seems somewhat unlikely!). Or, did I diagnose the issue incorrectly in the first place?

I've used the same conversion / serialization code in other places and its worrying that I'm propagating a fix for an issue that might only be relevant in the original ACO scenario, thus introducing other errors elsewhere.

I have tried searching for answers, but come up with a blank. I've actually avoided posting this question for months with my uncertainty over the root cause, but I would like an answer if someone knows.

Comment: Looks like those 3rd-party applications are buggy.  But you're also destroying information by using `System.Drawing.Color`, you should use a type with 16 bits of precision per channel.  Your original `WriteInt16` is correct, don't change it.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Thanks for the insight. In truth this was my original assumption when this first came to light, but I decided that was ego talking and it couldn't be possible that everyone else was doing it wrong. As I briefly noted, I do use a custom type now, although there's still more to be done in regards to editing ranges.

Comment: It also seems like whatever tool generated those `.aco` files is basically writing numbers like 00, 11, 22, etc. so it doesn't matter which "digit" gets read first.  Perhaps they are aware of their own endianness bug and that's their workaround.